# Can I visit relatives in the US on a B1/B2 visa?

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas, change-purpose-of-travel

I have B1/B2 visa and traveled to the US for a business trip from my company couple time. I am recently married and my wife is on H1B status from 1 1/2 yrs. I am planning to visit the US in coming months.

Questions:

1. Will I be eligible travel US on personal visit?
2. My wife is sponsoring for my trip, what documents do I need to carry along with
   me?
3. What queries I might face at port of entry?

Comment: See also http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/19707/i-have-a-b1-b2-visa-can-i-visit-my-husband-in-the-us?rq=1 (an almost exact duplicate, unfortunately closed without answer) and http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/can-i-use-b1-b2-visa-to-travel-to-the-us-without-a-business-purpose (supposedly another duplicate but I don't know if it does fully address your questions).

Comment: hi, what questions i might face at port of entry ?

Comment: @Relaxed the second question you posted has no referenced answers...

Comment: @MeNoTalk Yes, I don't think the answers are very good but since it's on a related topic and was mentioned as a duplicate of the first one, I thought it could be relevant.

Comment: @Relaxed perhaps they can merge both..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Will I be eligible travel US on personal visit?**

According to the [official U.S. Visas page](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/english/visit/visitor.html), you can use your B2 visa to visit friends or relatives:

> Tourism and Visit (B-2):
>
> - **visit with friends or relatives**

**My wife is sponsoring for my trip, what documents do I need to carry along with me?**

Usually, you will not need to bring anything specific, the documents to prove the ability to pay for the trip for nonimmigrant visas are required during the visa interview, and visa is issued after they are sure you can cover the trip financially and you have strong ties to your home. Anyway, to be in the safe side bring the following:

- A letter of employment from your current employer, just to prove that you have strong ties to your home. This is actually might be needed in case the officer suspected that you have intentions of exceeding your stay.
- A letter from your relatives in the U.S. will be a good idea to prove that you can cover the trip financially.
- Your return ticket.

**What queries I might face at port of entry?**

The usual: The purpose of the visit, how long you intend to stay, etc. You can actually never expect what other questions you might be asked.

Comment: hi, what letter do i need from relative soft or hard copy?

Comment: For safety always carry the original hard copy